# PHP regex for a word collection around a search phrase

Tags: php, regex

Hi I am trying to create a regex that will do the following

grab 5 words before the search phrase (or x if there is only x words there) and 5 words after the search phrase (or x if there is only x words there) from a block of text (when I say words I mean words or numbers whatever is in the block of text)

eg

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit your user page to set your name and email.

if you was to search "visit" it would return:
Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit your user page to set

the idea is to use preg_match_all in php to give me a bunch of search results showing where in the text the search phrase appears for each occurrence  of the search phrase.

Thanks in advance :D

on a sub note there may be a better way to get to my result if you feel there is please feel free to throw it in the pool as I'm not sure this is the best just the first way I thought of, to do what I need :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
(\S+\s+){0,5}\S*\bvisit\b\S*(\s+\S+){0,5}
```

will match five "words" (but accepting less if the text is shorter) before and after your search word (in this case `visit`).

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(\S+\s+){0,5} # Match five (or less) "words"
    \S*             # Match (if present) punctuation before the search term
    \b              # Assert position at the start of a word
    visit           # Match the search term
    \b              # Assert position at the end of a word
    \S*             # Match (if present) punctuation after the search term
    (\s+\S+){0,5}   # Match five (or less) "words"
    /ix', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

I'm defining a "word" as a sequence of non-whitespace characters, separated by at least one whitespace.

The search words should be actual words (starting and ending with an alphanumeric character).

Comment: +1 for using a real regex. But you don't need the \S*\b stuff. Assuming your search word is $keyword, '/(\S+\s+){0,5}' . $keyword . '(\s+\S+){0,5}/' works just fine.

Comment: It's not needed in this example text. But it is needed if the keyword may be surrounded by something other than whitespace. Let's say the keyword was `Overflow`, then you need `(\S+\s+){0,5}\S*\boverflow\b\S*(\s+\S+){0,5}` or you won't get a match.

Comment: Thank you, my completed code.`<?php $preg_safe = str_replace(" ", "\s", preg_quote($search));
                $pattern = "/(\w*\S\s+){0,8}\S*\b($preg_safe)\b\S*(\s\S+){0,8}/ix"; 
                
                if(preg_match_all($pattern, $row['news_text'], $matches)){
                    $row['extract'] = str_replace(strtolower($search), "<span class='searched-for'>$search</span>", strtolower($matches[0][0]));
                }else{
                    $row['extract'] = false;
                } ?>`

Comment: Any chance of an edit that will support multiple words e.g. "visit your user", would appreciate it.

Comment: @Tom: This regex uses verbose mode where whitespace is ignored in order to improve readability. This means also that if you want to match a phrase that contains whitespace, you need to write it as `visit\syour\suser` (for any whitespace) or `visit\ your\ user`/`visit[ ]your[ ]user` (for actual space characters).

Comment: I was just about to comment back, it was simply my idiot-icy not converting spaces to "\s". Thanks for the speedy response.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the folowing (it is a bit computation heavy, so it woudn't be efficient for very long strings):

```
<?php
$phrase = "Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit your user page to set your name and email.";
$keyword = "Visit";
$lcWords = preg_split("/\s/", strtolower($phrase));
$words = preg_split("/\s/", $phrase);
$wordCount = 5;

$position = array_search(strtolower($keyword), $lcWords);
$indexBegin =  max(array($position - $wordCount, 0));
$len = min(array(count($words), $position - $indexBegin + $wordCount + 1));
echo join(" ", array_slice($words, $indexBegin, $len));
//prints: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit your user page to set
```

[Codepad example here](http://codepad.org/Xm2YHddx)