# How can I get a summary string around a search query within a longer string?

Tags: php, string, text

When presenting search results I need to provide a preview string that contains the search term, similar to how Google displays results.

How can I get the context of the search term within a longer string without dividing any words?

Example:

Given the long string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
```

And the search term: `sed diam nonummy`

How can I programmatically return the result:

> ...consectetuer adipiscing elit, **sed diam nonummy** nibh euismod tincidunt...

I'm using three words around the search term above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me, with help Tim Pietzcker on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743217/php-regex-for-a-word-collection-around-a-search-phrase).

```
<?php
function summarize($haystack,$needle,$wordLimit = 5) {

    // first get summary of text around key word (needle)
    $preg_safe = str_replace(" ", "\s", preg_quote($needle));
    $pattern = "/(\w*\S\s+){0,$wordLimit}\S*\b($preg_safe)\b\S*(\s\S+){0,$wordLimit}/ix";
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $haystack, $matches)) {
        $summary = str_replace(strtolower($needle), "<strong>$needle</strong>", $matches[0][0]) . '...';
    } else {
        $summary = false;
    }

    return $summary;
}
$haystack = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.';
$needle = 'dolor sit amet';
echo summarize($haystack,$needle);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How large are your strings?

You could store each word and it's position in the string.

Then query and get the position, return [position - offset, position + offset] string.

You could use strpos to find the position of the term you are looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Then use the offset idea, or if you want to return full words, go char by char backwards until you find a space or the beginning of the string store that position. 
    Then go forward, same idea store that position. Then use substr ($string , int $leftpos , $rightpos - $leftpos )

Comment: Thanks zad.  My strings are typically about 1000 words.